# Can I enable Xbox 360 controller support?

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc, controllers

How can I enable Xbox 360 controller support in Mass Effect 3? Perhaps the ME3 Coalesced Editor will do the trick?

Comment: I presume you want to do this on the PC, correct?

Comment: It doesn't work by default?  That seems strange, this game is available on consoles as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

[Mass Effect 3 for PC does not natively support gamepads](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-02-16-bioware-explains-why-pc-mass-effect-3-doesnt-support-gamepads).

A project was being undertaken by [the community on Bioware's forums](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Gameplay-Strategy-amp-Builds-Discussion-Spoilers-allowed/Need-help-completing-Mass-Effect-3-PC-Gamepad-Support-15841155-1.html) but this hasn't been updated in many months and is incomplete - if you want partial gamepad support, you can download the coalesced files from that forum post.

Alternatively you could use something like Pinnacle Game Profiler or Xpadder to map your gamepad controls to the keyboard and mouse equivalents.

Comment: If you must use a gamepad, I'd *highly* recommend going the keymapping route, rather than the coalesced edits.

Comment: Can you give me more detail on how it is done ?

Comment: You get an application like Xpadder, install it, and then run it and bind your gamepad actions to correspond to keystrokes. It would be covered in the documentation for whichever application you got.

Comment: Strange, I remember playing ME 3 on PC with the 360 gamepad without any difficulties. Did EA drop support after some occult patch?

Comment: Nope, it never had support, there was an outcry about the fact a game that was coming out on the xbox didn't have support for a game pad (see the first linked article which pre-dates the release)